# How do I create a new row with all default values in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two columns, `id` and `created`. Both have default values, so I should be able to insert a new row without supplying any data.

However, this syntax does not work:

```
INSERT INTO books () VALUES ()
```

I would also like to return the generated `id` of the inserted row. This syntax also does not work:

```
INSERT INTO books () VALUES () RETURNING id
```

How do I write this query in Postgres SQL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [INSERT syntax:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

```
insert into books default values
returning id;
```

Answer (score 3):

here is example (basically, just use `DEFAULT`):

```
t=# create table d(i int default 0, t text default 'a');
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into d values(DEFAULT,DEFAULT) returning *;
 i | t
---+---
 0 | a
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify all values as `DEFAULT` in one expression?